# Windows 8 running Hyper V containing Windows XP with no connectivity

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, wireless-networking, dhcp, hyper-v

I've followed all the steps for setting up a VM and did it correctly.  The VM started, i installed windows and added a virtual switch(external) with the virtual switch manager.  I then added a legacy network adapter to the VM and chose "Virtual NIC" (the name I gave the virtual switch).

This all worked fine for a couple of days, then in the middle of using the machine, I got a limited or no connectivity warning when someone else logged onto the network(and entirely different computer in my house...just logged on and connected to the router, not my PC or VM).

Since then, I have been unable to regain connectivity.  I have disabled and renabled the adapters in the XP VM.  I have tried `ipconfig /release` and `ipconfig /renew`, which gives me the error that it has timed out contacting the DHCP.  The Windows 8 Network Connection screen shows 5 connections.  One is a TAP driver for my VPN(disabled).  One is my on board ethernet(disabled).  The other 3 are my wireless network card, a network bridge and vEthernet(Virtual NIC).

The properties of the network bridge shows it is using the Wireless NIC, and that the Hyper V Extensible Virtual Switch and the Microsoft MAC Bridge are being used.

I ideally want to not set a static IP on the VM.  Has anyone experienced this before?

---

Edit: It's worth mentioning that I had configured my router to have the VM in the DMZ.  It was like this initially, also.

Comment: I am currently assigning it a static IP to get it working.  The issue seems to be contacting the routers DHCP.  Strange how it did this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is it just won't connect to the DHCP any more.  I had to set a static IP to resolve, but it has been stable since.